# code working in home page but not in inner directory-just shows loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loading

my code works fine in home directory but in inner directory it keep on showing loading image.never shows original page

here is my simple code

```
   <html><head><style type="text/css" media="all">@import "http://static.something.com/files/common_css/style16.css";</style>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


       <script src="http://static.something.com/js/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://something.com/js/jquery.form33.js"></script>              <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()})    </script>  
       </head><body>


     <?php


   echo'    <body style="cursor:auto" id="curpo" onLoad="$.image({ ajax: \'http://something.com/jquery/desigirls/77987\' });return false;" class="uiMediaThumb uiMediaThumbLarge uiMediaThumbAlb uiMediaThumbAlbLarge"></body>
';

      ?></body></html>
```

this code works fine here http://something.com/testage.php

but not works in this page http://www.something.com/touch/w2et/testage.php

everything is same.i think there is some issue with javascript or image references.i tried changing all but same problem.

here is jsbin link as well
       jsbin.com/royepawomi/edit

here also it is not working

Comment: Why do you want to have two <body>-s in your document? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two links you have posted are two different domains

`www.way2enjoy.com` and `way2enjoy.com`.  I would suggest picking just one and using that.

The reason for this is you cannot do cross domain AJAX requests.  Having the www. in one means they are treated as separate domains.